# getRepositoryToken() method for mocking repository is not working with dataSource.getRepository()

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to create a mock of repository using getRepositoryToken() method. In service file I am fetching repository with dataSource.getRepository(Entity). So far I came to know getRepositoryToken() works with injectRepository() decorator.
What should I use instead of getRepositoryToken() to make it work with dataSource.getRepository(Entity).

Attaching dummy code:
**UserService.ts:**

```
export class UserService {
  constructor(
    ......
    ......
  ) { }

  private userRepository = AppDataSource.getRepository(userEntity);
}
```

**user.test.ts**

```
 beforeAll(async () => {

    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        .....
        ....
        })
      ],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(userEntity),
          useFactory: mockUserRepository
        },
      ]
    }).compile();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would it? `AppDataSource` comes from the `typeorm` package (or an instance of `DataSource` from `typeorm` at least) where as `getRepositoryToken()` is a *helper* method from `@nestjs/typeorm` that is used to map the DI injection token to a value. By default, when you use `TypeormModule.forFeature()` and `@InjectRepository()` Nest will set up this `provide: getRepositoryToken(Repo), useValue: DataSource.getRepository(Repo)` (simplified obviously) for you, then when you use that same `getRepositoryToken` in your test you're ignoring the `TypeormModule.forFeature()`. Notice that this means that Nest doesn't change how TypeORM is working at all, if you still use `AppDataSource.getRepository()` then you need to mock `AppDataSource.getRepository()` directly.